# I need a macros button that creates a fully labelled, edited chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying for hours to create a macro that when selected creates my desired graph. I keep getting a 424 error and no chart titles, axis titles, or any chart edits can be made. I have looked at other forums and still can't seem to grasp what I need to do. For now, my macro is set to an unfinished chart. Not sure what to do to the code associated with my macro.  If someone could walk me through it, that would be awesome.  Below is my code thus far.

```
Sub CreateChart_Macro()
'
' CreateChart_Macro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
'
    Range("K1:L30").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$K$1:$L$30")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.5
    With ActiveChart.Axes()
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .DisplayUnit = xlHundreds
    End With
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 2.5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 0.5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 0.1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 0.2
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.5
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").ScaleWidth 1.04, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromBottomRight
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    With ActiveChart.Axes()
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .DisplayUnit = xlHundreds
    End With
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1
    Selection.MajorTickMark = xlInside
    Selection.MajorTickMark = xlOutside
    Selection.MajorTickMark = xlNone
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Crosses = xlAutomatic
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = xlThousands
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = xlNone
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).ReversePlotOrder = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).ReversePlotOrder = False
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.75
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1
    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementLeft 43.8
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementTop 1.8
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelTop)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 6
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 8
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 5.3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 12
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 10
    With ActiveChart.Axes()
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .DisplayUnit = xlThousands
    End With
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 2
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 10
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 3.3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 2
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 0.2
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 0.5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 4
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 2
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0.5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Crosses = xlAutomatic
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Crosses = xlMaximum
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Crosses = xlAutomatic
    With ActiveChart.Axes()
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .DisplayUnit = xlHundreds
    End With
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Laser Spot Diameter vs. MRR"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Laser Spot Diameter vs. MRR"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 27).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 23).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(24, 4).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = _
        "Material Removal Rate [mm^3/s]"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Material Removal Rate [mm^3/s]"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 30).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 30).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 10
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = _
        "Laser Spot Diameter [mm]"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Laser Spot Diameter [mm]"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 24).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 19).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 10
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(20, 5).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 10
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 247
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 245
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error? Most likely you shouldn't be working with `ActiveChart`.

Comment: `With ActiveChart.Axes()` looks off.

Comment: ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = _
        "Material Removal Rate [mm^3/s]"

Comment: That line spits out an error message here. y-axis won't label or appear at all